# Laravel Valet does not serve WebGL build, error 404

Tags: laravel, webgl, laravel-valet

My Laravel project has a WebGL build viewer/creator in the public/admin/creator and public/admin/viewer folders. On production and development servers this works fine. Locally running Laravel Valet I receive error 404 page not found.

WebGL folders have an index.html in their folders which should be served.

I think I may need an custom valet driver but don't know what this should contain and how to install.

Comment: Found out that if I add index.html to the url it does hit the webGL build. How to fix that it automatically hits this when in the folder. I'm using nginx btw.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you figure out how to get it to automatically serve index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by adding /index.html to the webGL route in my browser.